# Deploy ASP.Net Core with Plesk for Linux

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core, proxy, plesk

### **Following is my server environment**

- Server : VPS
- Host   : AWS EC2
- OS     : CentOS Linux 8.3.2011
- Plesk  : Plesk Obsidian 18.0.34
- .Net Version : .Net Core 3.0 (Installed manually from linux CLI)

### **What I am look for**

I am trying to deploy ASP.Net Core 3.0 api project to CentOS 8 server. Is there a way to use plesk to deploy this? May be by providing additional settings under "Apache & nginx Settings" (or any other way)?

### **Edit**

Tried following this article - [Error using ASP.NET Core in Ubuntu with Plesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773027/error-using-asp-net-core-in-ubuntu-with-plesk)

- Have turned off - Reverse Proxy Server (nginx) from plesk
- Added following configuration to "Additional Apache directive" under Apache & nginx Settings

.

```
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
```

But getting different error.

```
AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some detailed debugging and understanding how the flow works between Plesk, Apache, NginX and ASP.Net Core, managed to get it working.  Added following configuration to "Additional Apache directive" under Apache & nginx Setting.

```
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}

Protocols             h2 http/1.1

SSLEngine             on
SSLProtocol           all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder   off
SSLCompression        off
SSLSessionTickets     on
SSLUseStapling        off

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass             / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse      / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

**Key thing to notice** is that Proxy is redirecting to http and not https. But that is just internal in AWS server and user end is already protected by SSL configured through Apache.